# Push data into a array in a mongoDB schema using mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

Is it possible push into an array in a mongoDB schema.

**For example in the following schema:**

```
 var ProviderSchema = new Schema({
      keyWords: [String] 
  });
```

How can I push data into the keyWords using the route below:

```
 app.put('/providers/words/:provider_id', function(req, res) {
      // Push to array here
 })
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
app.put('/providers/words/:provider_id', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params('provider_id');
    var update = {$push: {"keyWords": "keyword"}}; // Push a keyword into the model array.
    ProviderSchema.findOneAndUpdate(id, update, function(err, provider){
        if(err) return err;
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this okay amendment okay "{ $push: {"keyWords": req.body.keywords}}" to get the input from the user

Comment: `{$pushAll: {keyWords: req.body.keywords}}`

Assuming req.body.keyWords is an array.